# Check that user entered three file names as input

Tags: bash

I have never done shell scripting before and need some help with a small project.

I want a user to enter three file names and check that the user has input THREE names and give an error if its more or less.  The files will be sorted into another file but that is working fine just having problem with checking what the user has entered.

I have tried

```
echo Please select the three files you want to use
read $file1 $file2 $file3

if ! [ $# -eq 3 ]; then
   echo "Please enter THREE values"
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without changing your `read` command:

```
if [ -z "$file1" -o -z "$file2" -o -z "$file3" ]; then
    echo "Please enter THREE values"
fi
```

But the preferred way is using arrays here:

```
read -a files
if [ ! ${#files[@]} -eq 3 ]; then
    echo "Please enter THREE values"
fi
```

And btw. the elements are `${files[0]}`, `${files[1]}` and `${files[2]}` or, you could loop the array:

```
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo $f
done
```

Comment: Thanks man this works perfectly, also thanks a lot for adding the elements as well saves me some time on looking those up.

Comment: I tried the moment I chose the answer but need to be rank 15 for that and still only 13, will upvote the moment I can promise

Comment: and just got the rank and upvoted thanks again man you were a great help

Answer (score 0):

You did well, the only problem is the use of `$` in your read statement. Remove dollars and your code will work:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Please select the three files you want to use"
read file1 file2 file3

#Or something like:
#echo -n "File 1:"
#read file1
#echo -n "File 2:"
#read file2
#echo -n "File 3:"
#read file3

echo "File 1: $file1  File 2 : $file2  File 3 : $file3"
```